# Read strings from USB-CDC; how to use stdio_set_chars_available_callback()?

Tags: c, usb, microcontroller, stdio, raspberry-pi-pico

I try to read strings transmitted over USB to the Raspberry Pi Pico using `stdio` within a callback function as soon as characters are available. I don't want to poll the interface or use a repeating timer. Because `UART0` and `UART1` are needed for other purposes and all PIO-State machines are toll used for even more UART interfaces, USB is the only option. PICO_SDK provides [`void stdio_set_chars_available_callback(void(*)(void *) fn, void *param)`](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/runtime.html#rpip3379999e6eaba62d3d5e) to get notified when characters are available.

I don't attempt to read strings, just a single character (as an integer) then echo the integer. When I can't read a char I can't read a string either. The real project is over 3000 lines long and build entirely on the concepts of interrupts and callbacks. Besides `UART0` and `UART1` I implemented `UART2`, `UART3`, `UART4` and `UART5` using the PIO-Statemachines. `getchar_timeout_us(0);` is not an option it would make parsing, checking byte spacing (time between bytes) harder.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

void callback(void *ptr){

    int *i = (int*) ptr;  // cast void pointer back to int pointer
    // read the character which caused to callback (and in the future read the whole string)
    *i = getchar_timeout_us(100); // length of timeout does not affect results
}

int main(){
    stdio_usb_init(); // init usb only. uart0 and uart1 are needed elsewhere
    while(!stdio_usb_connected()); // wait until USB connection
    int i = 0;
    stdio_set_chars_available_callback(callback, (void*)  &i); //register callback

    // main loop
    while(1){
        if(i!=0){
            printf("%i\n",i); //print the integer value of the character we typed
            i = 0; //reset the value
        }
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The callback works. I tested it by enabling the LED inside the callback. When I typed in the terminal the LED turned on. The passing of the void pointer works too. The value is changed by the callback. I assume the issue is `*i = getchar_timeout_us(100);`. The function returns `-1`, not the ASCII (integer) value of the character I typed. [`get_char_timeout_us()`](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/runtime.html#rpip3af6c51330bd3e16a23b) returns `PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT` macro when timeout occurs. I timeout reading a char within the callback notifying characters are available to read.

The 100 μs in `getchar_timeout_us(100);` is chosen because it is not much greater than the minimum time between bytes at a baudrate of 115200. The minimum time would be 86,805 μs. Maybe too fast to type but I'll write a Python script sending the strings to the Raspberry Pi Pico.

I expect reading a character within the callback notifying that characters are available would return the send character and not `PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT`. My assumption was timeout of 100 μs in `getchar_timeout_us(100);` was too short to type a character. Although there should be at least a single character in buffer because else the callback shouldn't have triggered. I increased the timeout to 1,000,000 μs, so 1 second. Still `PICO_ERROR_TIMEOUT`.

I tried multiple terminals, usually I use PySerial [`serial.tools.miniterm`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.miniterm) on Windows. I also tried Minicom and screen on Fedora Linux 38 (different computer), no different result. Getting rid of the timeout by using `getchar();` leads to callback getting blocked indefinitely. It appears characters typed disappear into the void when I enter the callback. My assumption is `getchar_timeout_us(100);` and `getchar();` are the wrong functions. What are the correct functions to call? Or how do I use the existing function to read the characters in the buffer?

CMakeList.txt:

```bash
# Generated Cmake Pico project file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Initialise pico_sdk from installed location
# (note this can come from environment, CMake cache etc)
set(PICO_SDK_PATH "../../pico-sdk")

set(PICO_BOARD pico CACHE STRING "Board type")

# Pull in Raspberry Pi Pico SDK (must be before project)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

if (PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS "1.4.0")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Raspberry Pi Pico SDK version 1.4.0 (or later) required. Your version is ${PICO_SDK_VERSION_STRING}")
endif()

project(foo C CXX ASM)

# Initialise the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

# Add executable. Default name is the project name, version 0.1

add_executable(foo src/foo.cpp )

target_include_directories(foo
  PUBLIC
    include/
)

pico_set_program_name(foo "foo")
pico_set_program_version(foo "0.1")

pico_enable_stdio_uart(foo 0) # disable stdio over UART we need it
pico_enable_stdio_usb(foo 1)  # enable stdio over USB

# Add the standard library to the build
target_link_libraries(foo
        pico_stdlib)

# Add the standard include files to the build
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/.. # for our common lwipopts or any other standard includes, if required
)

pico_add_extra_outputs(foo)
```

Terminal output:

```bash
py -m  serial.tools.miniterm COM14 115200
--- Miniterm on com14  115200,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1

--- exit ---
```

I typed Hello `(72, 101, 108, 108, 111)` but got `(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)`. This:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    //stdio_init_all();
    stdio_usb_init(); // init usb only. uart0 and uart1 are needed elsewhere
    while(!stdio_usb_connected()); // wait until USB connection
    while(1){
        int i = getchar_timeout_us(100);
        if(i >= 0){
            printf("%i", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

works. When I type `Hello` I get `(72, 101, 108, 108, 111)` as expected. Making `i` `volatile` does not change the output and because void pointer is not supposed to be volatile it throws a warning. Replacing `i` with a global `volatile int g = 0` (no example) variable either.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

void callback(volatile void *ptr){

    volatile int *i = (volatile int*) ptr;  // cast void pointer back to int pointer
    // read the character which caused to callback (and in the future read the whole string)
    *i = getchar_timeout_us(100); // length of timeout does not affect results
}

int main(){
    stdio_usb_init(); // init usb only. uart0 and uart1 are needed elsewhere
    while(!stdio_usb_connected()); // wait until USB connection
    volatile int i = 0;
    stdio_set_chars_available_callback(callback, (volatile void*)  &i); //register callback

    // main loop
    while(1){
        if(i!=0){
            printf("%i\n",i); //print the integer value of the character we typed
            i = 0; //reset the value
        }
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Putting `gpio_put(PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN, 1)` after `*i = getchar_timeout_us(100);` in the callback will turn on the LED. Putting `gpio_put(PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN, 0)` after `sleep_ms(1000);` in the main loop will *not* turn off the LED, as would be expected.

Comment: In your example code, there isn't much point to using the callback.  How about you just call `getchar_timeout_us(0)` in the main loop?  I've successfully read data from USB before by doing that.

Comment: @DavidGrayson. I agree, that there is no point for a callback in the example. 

The real project has over 3000 Lines of Code using up to 6-UART ports 2 Native and 4 via PIO and is entirely based on callbacks/interrupts for every UART port.

I send a protocol and with in-frame defined length. Having `getchar_timeout_us(0)` would make it more difficult to check if all bytes arrived in a timely manner, it wouldn't be a great solution because it could cause framing issues.

Comment: Fine, but simplifying the code would help reveal what is working and what isn't.  For example, maybe the callback is called in an interrupt and you're not properly dealing with the complexities of interrupts (I don't see a `volatile` or memory barrier).  So if we just try not using a callback, we eliminate that as something that can cause problems.

Comment: @DavidGrayson first and foremost thanks for the help. 

Unfortunately `volatile` did not change the output. I also attempted to replace the passed `volatile int i` which is passed to the callback with a global variable `volatile int g`  to removed the uncertainty that this could be the cause of the issue.

I too wrote a very simple echo program **without** the callback (see edit of the original post) which works as you expect. It echo the typed characters (or the ascii integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the Mutex handling in `stdio_usb.c` https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/6a7db34ff63345a7badec79ebea3aaef1712f374/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c

Commenting the Mutex code out in `stdio_usb_in_chars()`, as shown below, will "fix" the issue.

Seems like there is a bug when attempting to get a Mutex in the callback function.  Looks like stdio_usb_out_chars() blocks at mutex_try_enter_block_until() waiting for the Mutex that's held (and never released) in low_priority_worker_irq()

```
int stdio_usb_in_chars(char *buf, int length) {
// note we perform this check outside the lock, to try and prevent possible deadlock conditions
// with printf in IRQs (which we will escape through timeouts elsewhere, but that would be less graceful).
//
// these are just checks of state, so we can call them while not holding the lock.
// they may be wrong, but only if we are in the middle of a tud_task call, in which case at worst
// we will mistakenly think we have data available when we do not (we will check again), or
// tud_task will complete running and we will check the right values the next time.
//
int rc = PICO_ERROR_NO_DATA;
if (stdio_usb_connected() && tud_cdc_available()) {
    //if (!mutex_try_enter_block_until(&stdio_usb_mutex, make_timeout_time_ms(PICO_STDIO_DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT_MS))) {
    //    return PICO_ERROR_NO_DATA; // would deadlock otherwise
    //}
    if (stdio_usb_connected() && tud_cdc_available()) {
        int count = (int) tud_cdc_read(buf, (uint32_t) length);
        rc = count ? count : PICO_ERROR_NO_DATA;
    } else {
        // because our mutex use may starve out the background task, run tud_task here (we own the mutex)
        tud_task();
    }
    //mutex_exit(&stdio_usb_mutex);
}
return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use defines in CMakeLists.txt

https://www.opensourceagenda.com/projects/pico-sdk/versions

Added `stdio_set_chars_available_callback()` function to set a callback to be called when input is available. See also the new `PICO_STDIO_USB_SUPPORT_CHARS_AVAILABLE_CALLBACK` and `PICO_STDIO_UART_SUPPORT_CHARS_AVAILABLE_CALLBACK` defines which both default to 1 and control the availability of this new feature for USB and UART stdio respectively (at the cost of a little more code).

Comment: As I couldn't get stuck on this issue any longer without getting problems with my employee I just went with a semaphore which is released inside the callback, and than acquired later by the program.